# cross domain resource sharing in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess, cross-domain

I would like to get some suggestions on the cross domain ajax calls as i am new to the concept.
I have 2 servers A & B . I have complete hold over server A, while server B is a Client server with no control.

Server A(Apache server) makes a Ajax post request to Server B.

my .htaccess file in Server A

```
# with AJAX withCredentials=false (cookies NOT sent)
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"                   
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE" 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
RewriteEngine On                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]


    # with AJAX withCredentials=true (cookies sent, SSL allowed...)
    SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN (.*) ORIGIN=$1
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE" 
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN}e"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]
```

I am getting error "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present on requested resource." Is it possible to enable cross domain resource sharing without distrubing server B?

how can i add Access-Control-Allow-Origin"*" to the response header, so as to enable cross domain access. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `how can i add Access-Control-Allow-Origin"*" to the response header` Unless you control the server you're making the request to, you can't.

Comment: It is like telling your bank "Here is the password you need to have me use when I hack you"